# scala-xml for Scala 2.13 on Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, scala-xml

In order to make them fully JVM 11 compatible, I want to update several Scala scripts on Debian and Ubuntu systems from Scala 2.12.12 to Scala 2.13.3.

The first problem I encountered is that the scala-xml jar file is not included anymore. So I tried `sudo apt-get install -y scala-xml` which installed a very old version for Scala 2.11. So I removed that again.

Then I tried to find some deb package I could install manually using `dpkg`. But couldn't find anything for Scala 2.13.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

as this [question suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170384/not-able-to-install-scala-2-13-using-apt-get):

> Ubuntu repositories are always far behind latest versions. Did you try to download the last official deb package, then `sudo dpkg -i scala-2.13.0.deb && sudo apt install -f`

the download link:
https://scala-lang.org/download/

(and specifically the download for ubuntu/debian: https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.13.3/scala-2.13.3.deb )

Comment: Thanks, but there is no download for scala-xml.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki/Getting-started this is the getting started of the scala-xml project on github